# function that can NULL a passed pointer

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

at the moment I have

```
void clistDeleteNode(clist_t *list,cnode_t **pnode) {
    cnode_t *node=*pnode;

    /* stuff done with node here, removed for clarity */

    free(*pnode);
    *pnode=0;
}
```

which is called with

```
clistDeleteNode(list,&aNode);
```

The function automatically NULL's the end user pointer after its freed - I do this as it makes debugging and leak checking easier.

is there a more elegant way to pass a pointer to a function such as it an be modified without having to use **&**aNode ? (from the end users point of view)

Comment: Not without abusing macros...

Comment: `&` is but a single character and makes it clear that the value may be modified, not just used. I'm not sure how you could improve on it.

Comment: it was only really because it's different to all the other functions (in the group of related functions) - I didn't know if there wasn't some way to mark a parameter as "by reference" for example in just the function decleration

Comment: https://github.com/chriscamacho/clist put the whole (simple) project up on github - someone might find it useful but it was more for the intellectual challenge to be honest....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C++, there isn't a way of passing the address of `aNode` without having used the `&` operator in the calling function.

Using the pre-processor to hide what you're actually doing would most likely be considered a less "elegant" way than the above clear way.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such thing as *pass-by-reference* in C, passing a pointer to the type which you'd like to update in another function is the only and recommended way to enable changing the original variable.

---

#### Not recommended.. really, please don't use it.

I've seen developer (long time since last though) use something as the below just to make things *"easier"*, but to be honest I think it causes more headache than beauty.

```
#define REF(v) (&v)
#define REF_TO(type, v) type *v
#define DEREF(p) (*p)

void
func (REF_TO(int*, p))
{
  DEREF(p) = 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int *p;

  func (REF(p));

  return 0;
}
```

### DO - NOT - USE - IT, SERIOUZLY.

Comment: Yes, that code is horrendous.  I'd recommend removing it, because it's best not give anybody ideas...

Comment: gggaaah oh my eyes - its more complex not more elegant!

Comment: @ChrisCamacho exactly, stick with the more elegant ampersand, `&`!

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you want a function to modify `x`, you need to pass `&x` to the function, no matter what the type.

You could hide this behind macros, but that may ultimately prove more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's ugly; you can simulate reference parameters using array types and array-pointer decay.

```
typedef void (*void_ptr_ref)[1];
void func(void_ptr_ref p) {
    p[0] = 0;
}
int main() {
    void_ptr_ref p;
    func(p);
    /* do stuff with p */
}
```

Posix actually uses this (horrendous!) style for the `jmp_buf` type (used in [`setjmp.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h)).

This is only really worthwhile if your "pointer" type is intended to be used as an opaque type; you certainly don't want users having to double-indirect the `void_ptr_ref p` or have to cast it etc.